# Python connection with oracle 11g

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I need to connect my DB to python, i tried with:

```
cx_oracle.connect()
```

But i don't know what arguments it need.

This is an example of how I connected to the same DB in java, and it works perfectly.

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","System","mypassword");
```

Comment: Have you searched about it?

Comment: Have you tried [reading the manual](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#cx_Oracle.connect)?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i connect.

```
ip = 'Your IP'
port = 1521
SID = 'Your SID'
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, SID)

db = cx_Oracle.connect('username', 'password', dsn_tns)
```

Comment: You're apparently not using the JDBC driver, and he is, in which case this isn't going to do him much good.